# FindLabel vbScript expression not working?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, vbscript

Below expression is not working

```
Function FindLabel ( [NameEnglish], [Remarks], [FacilityType] )
    namh = ""
    rems = ""
    fact = ""    

    if not isnull (  [NameEnglish] )  then
        namh = [NameEnglish]
     elseif not isnull  (  [Remarks] ) or (([Remarks]) <> "")  then
        rems = [Remarks]
      elseif not isnull (  [FacilityType] ) then
        fact = [FacilityType]
    end if

    FindLabel = namh & " " & rems & " " & fact
End Function
```

I want to fulfill condition when Remarks is NULL & Remarks having "" means blank

Comment: Python works better with null values, use `[field] == None` for this condition.

Comment: Can you please give me full expression in Python

Comment: What happens when you use that code?  Are there errors, or nothing appears, or everything appears?

Comment: Other values appears but  where Remarks is blank nothing appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the `or` to an `and`

```vbs
elseif (not isnull ([Remarks])) and ([Remarks] <> "") then
```